# Wrong Autoprefixer compilation on linear-gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients, codekit

Im using Codekit 2 (2.0.4) with Autoprefixer-

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, black, white);
```

turned into this:

```
background: linear, to top, black, white;
```

Comment: The involvement of Codekit makes this difficult for anyone to troubleshoot - I suggest talking to the Codekit devs. Massive -1 for the unhelpful soul who downvoted this without comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was on old Autoprefixer version and was fixed in newest one. But it is difficult to update Autoprefixer separated of CodeKit (it is one of benefits of using Grunt).

Comment: This is happening for me too, I am building with the `grunt-postcss` plugin  `https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss` (0.5.5) that is requiring `https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core.git` (5.2.1) any idea as to why this is happening in the latest build?